# Generating unique salt (non-validated example given)

Tags: php, salt

I am redesigning my application where I need to have an unique salt.

I provide the way it is and I look forward to hear if this does not work the correct way or other ways I can improve it.

```
public function generatesalt($x=0)
{
    $x++;

    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $salt = substr($string, 0, 12);

    $stored = array();
    $qw = $this->registry->dbi->query("SELECT `salt` FROM `".PRE."membership`")->results();
    foreach ($qw as $k => $v)
        $stored[] = $v['salt'];


    if (in_array($salt,$stored))
        return $this->generatesalt($x);

    return $salt." /// ".$x;
}
```

Thanks. Again, my question is if this looks to work the correct way and you can't see serious disadvantages.

Comment: Surely it would be better to simply ensure your salt is generated in a cryptographically secure way - then there is no need to ensure uniqueness?

Comment: Hell, you don't even need that if all you're doing is using it when hashing a user's password in a membership provider...

Comment: thanks guys, I understand. I'll get rid of it for this case, and learn cryptographically secure way after.

Comment: Fetching *all* salts from the database is an extremely bad idea (what if the database, one day, contains 1 million rows?). However, in a normal use case you'll be fine with just `uniqid(rand(), true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't storing salts in a database that also contains the password hashes defeat the purpose of having an unknown string added to your pre-hashed string?

If a hacker gets database access, and only database access, they'll have the salts and hashes. If you have a static salt declared in a PHP define, they'll need server access as well as database access to get the same information.

Also relevant, you should remove the Output privilege from your SQL user if possible, so that a hacker [can't put shells on your server with just database access](http://evilzone.org/tutorials/upload-shell-with-sql-injection/) and get your PHP-defined salt.

Comment: Not really. Using a salt basically just means that precomputed dictionary attacks dont work. So long as the hash algorithm is strong enough it makes no difference where the salt is.

Comment: Perhaps the salt doesn't need to be secret or stored elsewhere, but I'm sure any hacker that knows what they're doing will add a prefix to their script for salts. If your salt is unknown, or even if it's unknown that you have a salt, it makes it that much harder for the hacker.

Also, I agree that the salt itself isn't important, but the knowledge of the existence of a salt, and knowledge of what the salt is is very important.

Comment: I think I made up my mind on what I ask. @chrisb thanks for your contribution for my question.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy - You are mixing up the salt with a secret pepper, these are two different things with different purposes. Add a secret pepper if you want, but the salt fullfills it's purpose even when known.

Answer (score 3):

Well, theoretically, salts only need to be unique in the sense that no other password should be hashed using that salt. The idea is to make it infeasible for bad guys to crack the hashes. If you use a salt, and you hash the password correctly (i.e. using something like bcrypt, scrypt, pbkdf2, etc.), then it will take a long time to crack just a handful of passwords -- let alone an entire database.

In practice randomly generated salts that are sufficiently long are not likely to occur more than once, so they should be more than fine.

In PHP a simple way of generating salts is to use `mcrypt_create_iv()`. It generates random bits from the system, which can be encoded for easier storage:

```
function randomSalt($length = 16) {
    $bits = mcrypt_create_iv($length);
    $encoded = base64_encode($bits);
    return substr($encoded, 0, $length);
}
echo randomSalt(); // Something like: "Yt5iX/LvdxOyxCiX"
```

Finally, salts do not have to be a secret. That is not why salts are used. Imagine you want to walk over to the corner shop. It takes 5 minutes. Now, imagine that you are forced to take a 24-hour detour. That is the salt. It is a huge road-bump that bad guys need to get over every time they crack a new hashed password. (Note: the 24 hours are just an example -- how long it takes depends on a few things, but you get the idea.)

Comment: If a hacker has the value of the salt, can't they just update whatever script they're using to try to crack the hash to append the salt to its guess before it's hashed, thus defeating the point of the salt?

Comment: @MisterMelancholy Sure, but it is not "just" something they can do. Theoretically it is relatively easy to crack salted passwords, but *practically* it will not be feasible. It is, of course, assuming that the password is hashed correctly. It is very easy to bungle it up if you are not sure what you are doing. You should always use known and tested ways of hashing passwords, such as the `crypt()` function, or a library such as PHPass.